# Java - TreeMap Solution

Tags: java, data-structures

I haven't done Java in a while and i need some suggestions and idea's regarding data structures.

Currently i am using a TreeMap  to map String values to Integer value.  I now need to do some calculations and divide the Integer value of the map entry by the the size of the whole map and store this for each entry.  I was thinking about using a Map,Integer> but is there a 3 way generics data structure in Java?

My current solution for this is this ..

```
            int treeSize = occurrence.size();
            String [][] weight = new String[treeSize][2];
            int counter=0;
            double score =0;
            for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : occurrence.entrySet()) {
                weight[counter][0]=entry.getKey();
                score=entry.getValue()/treeSize;
                weight[counter][1]= Double.toString(score);
                counter++;
              }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another object to hold this data:

```
public Data {
    private int value;
    private double score;

    ...
}
```

And then type the map as `Map<String, Data>`. After inserting all the values, you can iterate over the values and update the `ratio` property for each value in the map. For example:

```
double size = myMap.size();
for(Map.Entry<String, Data> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
    Data data = entry.getValue();
    data.setScore(data.getValue() / size); 
}
```

**EDIT**

Another thought just came to mind. Instead of calculating the values *after* you have inserted it, you should probably calculate it as you are inserting it; it's more efficient that way. Of course, you can only do this if you know the total number of values beforehand.

An even better way is to perform the calculation only when you retrieve a value from the map. There are two advantages to this:

- You don't need a separate object. Just abstract the access of the value from the map inside another function which returns the value associated with the key, divided by the size of the map.
- Since you don't have a separate object to maintain the calculated value, you don't need to update it every time you add or delete a new value.

Comment: I was thinking about creating my own Generic class, nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map.Entry<Integer, Double>` to hold the two values.  (Ultimately, you'd use either AbstractMap.SimpleEntry or AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry)

So your TreeMap would be `TreeMap<String, Map.Entry<Integer, Double>>`

However, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, I'd strongly suggest that you do the calculation on the fly.  Recalculating *every* fraction *every time* anything is inserted or deleted is time consuming, and churns small little objects, so it's likely to be *slower* than just doing the calculation.  Also, recalculation will cause threading issues if multiple threads access the TreeMap.  Instead, something like

```
public synchronized double getFraction(String key) {
   Integer value = theTreeMap.get(key);
   if (value == null)
      return 0.0;  // or throw an exception if you prefer...

   // note, since the Map has at least one entry, no need to check for div by zero
   return value.doubleValue() / theTreeMap.size();
}
```

Comment: I decided to add it to an ArrayList<Double> and score it all after they all get added to the Map.  Then use indexOf(Collections.max(list)) to get the index of the highest score and retrieve it from the Map using the index.  Is this a suitable way of doing it?  You are right by doing it on the fly since it saves time.

Comment: That's one way.  You can go simply `ArrayList<Double> sorter = new ArrayList(theTreeMap.values());`, then either sort it or just use Collections.max().

Comment: Oops - cancel the "sort" from my previous comment.  Sorting the values loses the index!  Must use Collections.max().  Or, you could make a List of the _entries_, and sort them, using a Comparator that compares the values.  Much more general purpose.  It's possible that Guava or Apache already have code to do that.